# Failed validation on 'Id' field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a simple MVC model like so:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide a name for the blah blah blah")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

...and I have a view like so (simplified):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<CompanyName.Web.Models.SomeClassViewModel>" %>

<form method="post" action="/someclass/add">
    <%=Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SomeClass.Id)%>

    <div>
        <%=Html.LabelFor(m => m.SomeClass.Name)%>
        <%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeClass.Name, new { @class = "form-medium" })%>
    </div>
</form>
```

On form submit, my controller validates the `ModelState` like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Models.SomeClassViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I get a model validation error of

> "The Id field is required."

Why is this occuring?

The `Id` field is getting assigned to 0 by default (as it should), and it will then be passed into the data layer for record creation, so I don't see what the problem is?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When/where is the 'Id' field being set to 0?

Comment: Is your id field an identity field in your database?

Comment: Making id nullable would probably fix the issue as MVC probably wants a value for a value type (int), but you might want to wait for better answers if the id really should be 0 (not just null) initially.

Comment: Could you show the `SomeClassViewModel` class? You have only shown the `SomeClass` model but not your main view model to which the view is strongly typed. I guess there you have some non nullable field which is not included in your form.

Comment: @MattJohnson I think the OP is referring to the fact that ints get 0 as their default assignment.

Comment: @Grumbler85 - Yes the Id column maps to an identity column.

Comment: @Grumbler85 - Yes the Id column maps to an identity column.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - The SomeClassViewModel class is just a simple class declaration with some property called 'SomeClass' of type 'SomeClass'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found out the problem.

Inside the constructor of my view model class ('SomeClassViewModel'), I added a line of code that called the default constructor for the 'SomeClass' property.

I figured this out by inspecting the ModelState error for the 'Id' validation key, and saw that the 'AttemptedValue' property was an empty string, where it should have been 0. Instantiating this property to an instance of 'SomeClass' fixed it.

I hope this can help someone possibly in the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change to name of the Id variable or change the data type to string?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the `Models.SomeClassViewModel` class also has the `Id` field, of the same type and variable name.

If this is not the case, you could also try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(SomeClass model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work because the input field names inside the form are prefixed with `SomeClass.`.

Comment: Well, fair enough. As long as `Models.SomeClassViewModel` has the `Id` field it should be fine.

Comment: Why would adding Id to the view model class stop the validation error from occurring on the model class?

Comment: The error more than likely happens because `Models.SomeClassViewModel` cannot bind.